# How can I add prefix to the name field of group model in django

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to extend the group model(add a new field called display field) and rename the name field of the django by adding some prefix(it would be company_id later on).
Till now I have just added the extra field to default group model like this

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

Group.add_to_class('display_field', models.CharField(max_length=180,null=True, blank=True))
```

How can I rename the name field now?

Comment: Dynamically adding fields in this manner breaks Django's migrations, and might cause other problems.  Why do you need to add these fields to Group?

Comment: I want  to change the default group name to something like company_id+group_name so thatevery role is unique for a company. Thats why i want to add a new field to the table which can be displayed to the user.

Comment: How else can I achieve both of my goals?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach for subclassing `auth.Group` is to use a **[`OneToOne`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#one-to-one-relationships)** relationship:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    group = models.OneToOneField('auth.Group', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Alternatively, you can use **[model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)**:

```
class Company(Group):
    name = models.CharField()
```

Comment: how can I add prefix to the name field then?

Comment: @AartiJoshi Why do you need a prefix?  Also, where does the prefix come from?

Comment: I might have several companies in my database and each company can have the same role. I want to differentiate between the roles by adding the company_id before the role name

Comment: for now, it can be a random string, later on it would be the company id

Comment: @AartiJoshi If companyA is using the same role as companyB, then you wouldn't want to append `companyA_id` to the name of that role if it would also be used by companyB... right?

Comment: Perhaps when you say "role", you mean [`Permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization)?